# how to paint an ellipse by pressing the button

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I want to paint an ellipse using the click button. But I can't connect the click button to paintEvent. e.g., If the button is pressed the ellipse should be green otherwise it should be red.

Comment: Add a snippet of code that you are working with so people have some context.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the button's `clicked()` signal to a custom slot on the widget that paints your ellipse.  Then in your custom slot, set the new colour, and call `update()` - this will trigger `paintEvent(..)` to be called when the event queue gets to the request.

Comment: When I press the button I got the error ..... TypeError: changecolor() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what is wrong, you are calling `changeColor(...)` with one argument but it takes two.